# How to use Stripe to collect card information without using form

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm new to Stripe. I'm trying to use Stripe for payment function. I found Checkout and Elements all require building a form. However, I can't find a way to pass card info as parameters to Stripe directly without using form. So i'm wondering is it possible to use Stripe without form on client side?

Comment: Sorry. How do you want to collect card info from user without using form?

Comment: @Zico I just want to use my own form collect card info, then pass card info to my own js function which holds stripe. But I don't want to use form provided by stripe, such as Checkout or Elements

Comment: You can try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42963215/1125284)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating stripe token using separate elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962752/creating-stripe-token-using-separate-elements)