# How to customize the payment method in payment intent example in stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to follow the example shown in the following link https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment.

I have the following code in the client side

```
 var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {
    placeholder:'',
    style: style
});
var cardexpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry',{
    placeholder:'',
    style:style
});
var cardCVV = elements.create('cardCvc',{
    placeholder:'',
    style:style
});


// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
cardNumber.mount('#card-element');
cardexpiry.mount("#card-expiry")
cardCVV.mount("#card-cvv")
```

instead of this

```
var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
card.mount("#card-element");
```

Because the I wanted to some UI manipulation. According to the code posted in the link
I should do the following

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
 stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
   payment_method: {card: card}
 }).then(function(result) {
 if (result.error) {
  // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
  console.log(result.error.message);
 } else {
  // The payment has been processed!
  if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
    // Show a success message to your customer
    // There's a risk of the customer closing the window before callback
    // execution. Set up a webhook or plugin to listen for the
    // payment_intent.succeeded event that handles any business critical
    // post-payment actions.
    }
 }
});
});
```

However in the example above in the payment_method the card object is passed, which is not the case in my code. How can I pass my card number and exp/date as well CVC separately in the  stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
       payment_method: {card: card}

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I ended up using the same code supplied by stripe but i managed to style it

Comment: can you share the code sample or github page, there is close to no info besides docs. I really need to split the elements or at least be able to style it according to business requirements. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this code

```
var stripe = Stripe('#YOUR KEY');
var elements = stripe.elements();

/// STYLE HERE
var style = {
    base: {
        fontSize: '16px',
        color: "#32325d",
        '::placeholder': {
            color: '#CFD7E0',
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {
    hidePostalCode: true,
    placeholder: '',
    style: style,



});
card.mount('#card-element');

card.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = '';
    } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems there is no opportunity to get card data from different card elements for now.

Answer (score 9):

There was a similar question about [how to call `stripe.createToken()` when you aren't using a `card` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962752/creating-stripe-token-using-separate-elements).

According to [the Stripe documentation for createToken](https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardNumberElement):

> The cardNumber Element you wish to tokenize data from. If applicable, the Element **pulls data from other elements you’ve created on the same instance of Elements** to tokenize—you only need to supply one Element as the parameter.

Now, for this case in particular, [the section for confirmCardPayment](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-with_element) says:

> Use stripe.confirmCardPayment with payment data from an Element by passing a card or **cardNumber** Element as payment_method[card] in the data argument.

Basically you just have to pass the `cardNumber` element to `payment_method["card"]` and it will pull the data from the other elements you’ve created.

```
...
stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
  payment_method: {card: cardNumber}
})
...
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I believe the Stripe documentation is very poor. When it comes to learning as beginner. https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/451
Anyways, thanks for this answer.

Comment: What about expiry date and CVC number, where to add those?

Comment: @Sayyamabbasi Here's an example with card number, expiry date and CVC elements: https://jsfiddle.net/AleFelix/pk4chy86/1/